# R data.table fread performance with and without colClasses

Tags: r, csv, data.table, set

I need to come up with a script that does set operation of diff between two vectors (to find the count of values that do not match). The first vector is a character vector (can change). This set will be diff'ed with 3000 other vectors that are read from csv files. All csv files are one column only and have unique values in them. Each file is anywhere from 1 to 60 MBs.

I am using data.table fread to read the csv files. However, I see that using colClasses option to read the values as characters increase the script time considerably. In the below script Option 1 takes about 10 seconds while Option 2 takes about 120 seconds. I want to read the columns as character. Why is this difference? Shouldn't the read take longer if it has to parse the values to find out the type? Also, how can I make the read quicker while keeping the type as character?

Code:

```
path <- "data/processed_data"
file_names <- list.files(here(path), pattern="csv")
v <- c("one", "two", "three")
v_count_unmatched <- integer()
  
for (fn2 in file_names) {
    f2 <- data.table::fread(here(path, fn2)) #### Option 1
    #f2 <- data.table::fread(here(path, fn2), colClasses = 'character') #### Option 2
    v_count_unmatched      <- c(v_count_unmatched, length(setdiff(v,f2 %>% pull() )))
}
```

I am using data.table version 1.13.6. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `fread` part which becomes slower? I think computing a setdiff between character vectors would be slower than for numeric vectors, maybe that's why the change makes the script slower. In RStudio you can use Tools > Profile Selected Lines to see the time for various parts of the script. If all you want is the number of different values, you don't need setdiff though, can do `sum(!vec1 %in% vec2)`

Comment: One of the culprit is the read part. because I benchmarked it commenting the diff part as well. The difference in seconds I posted is actually without the diff part.

Comment: Sorry, the question was a bit incorrect. I benchmarked with just the file loading part (not using the loaded data anywhere). This might resulted in some sort of lazy loading by which Option 1 was giving better results. I redid it using the data and the the difference is not that dramatic. Both are taking considerable time (> 100 seconds).